# How do I say If not found for date value

Tags: python

Hello I am writing to ask how to specify if a date is not found then execute.
THis is my code:

```
if get_slot_value('DATE'):
       print('date found')
if get_slot_value('DATE') == None:
       print('date not found')
```

I also tried these but when the date is not found nothing happens

```
if get_slot_value('DATE') is 'null':
if get_slot_value('DATE') != TRUE:
if get_slot_value('DATE') == FALSE :
if get_slot_value('DATE') == 'None':
```

Help

Comment: what does `get_slot_value` return?

Comment: is returns a date---if it when is checks and if  a date is present it will just print date found if is does not find a date then it will print out date nor found

Comment: and does it return `None`  when the date is not found...?

Comment: What's a date? A nanosecond value since some time epoch? A second value since some time epoch? A list with separated parts of a date? A dict with separated parts of a date? A string? What does it return when there is no date? We need to see your `get_slot_value()` function please.

Comment: And also, in python, it is `True`, `False`, `None`, note the capitalization and they are not enclosed in any types of quotes like `'`, `"`

Comment: It returns a string '12-march-2020', if nothing comes in it returns 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a function you are calling with parameter 'DATE':

```
if get_slot_value('DATE') == None:
```

If this is indexable and you are trying to get the value associated with key 'DATE' (is a string, list, or dictionary):

```
if get_slot_value['DATE'] == None:
```

`if condition` statements are equivalent to `if bool(condtion)`. Therefore, it will not find it if it is False, 0, or length 0.

**I recommend this** (because I think you are dealing with a dictionary):

```
if get_slot_value('DATE') == None:
    print('date not found')
else:
    print('date found')
```

You also might find this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_statement.asp) useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. In python there is something like 'null' until you are returning a string 'null' from you `get_slot_value()`, if you are not returning 'null' you can use `numpy.nan`
2. In python TRUE and FALSE are not valid untill you are not using them as a variable

   ```
   if get_slot_value('DATE') == numpy.nan:
   if get_slot_value('DATE') != True:
   if get_slot_value('DATE') == False :
   if get_slot_value('DATE') == None:
   ```